# C# Try/Catch Skips Nested If/Else Statement and Wont Open SaveDialog

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I am working on a school project but I cant figure out this last bug. It is supposed to open a saveFileDialog when the first if statement returns false. But instead of continuing on into the else statement, it goes straight to throwing the exception and never opens the saveFile Dialog. It gives me the following error: `Code: The path is not of a legal form.`

I dont understand what the problem is. The user should be able to select the path in the save dialog that pops up. The file doesnt exist yet and its supposed to open the save file dialog to make the file.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Declare StreamWriter object
        StreamWriter outputFile;

        // Try to write file
        try
        {
            // If current file is > 0
            if (new FileInfo(currentFile).Length > 0)
            {
               // Create output file using current file
               outputFile = File.CreateText(currentFile);

                // Loop through current file and write lines to output file
                for (int i = 0; i < lstBoxLog.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    outputFile.WriteLine(lstBoxLog.Items[i].ToString());
                }

                // Close text file
                outputFile.Close();
            }

            // Else open save dialog for user to save file
            else
            {
                // If save file dialog is equal to dialog result
                if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    // Open output file object with create text
                    outputFile = File.CreateText(saveFile.FileName);

                    // Set currentFile to = savefile dialog
                    currentFile = saveFile.FileName;

                    // Loop through each line and write to file
                    for (int i = 0; i < lstBoxLog.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        outputFile.WriteLine(lstBoxLog.Items[i].ToString());
                    }

                    // Close text file
                    outputFile.Close();
                }

                // Else show error message
                else
                {
                    // Display message box dialog
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot save file.", "Not Saved");
                } 
            }
        }

        // Display error message.
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Display message box dialog
            MessageBox.Show("Save canceled. \n\nCode: " + ex.Message, "Save Error!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: may be `currentFile` does not exists. what is the exception message?

Comment: sounds like `currentFile` contains an invalid path.  What is its value?

Comment: I just ran it with breakpoints and currentFile has the value " ".

The exception message is `Save Canceled. Code: The path is not of a legal form.`

Comment: If `currentFile` has no value - that should explain why you're getting an error? You can't save to a file called `" "`

Comment: That would make sense except that in my assignments vague instructions it tells me to set `currentFile =""`. Its supposed to open a save file dialog so that the user can set the file name and set the path.

Here's a snippet from the instructions: 
`Else, because we don’t have a currentfile filename set yet we need to use the SaveFileDialog to allow the user to choose an existing filename or provide a new filename to save.`

Comment: @RexLinder It's likely this line: `new FileInfo(currentFile).Length > 0`. You're asking it to convert to a path (but an empty string is an invalid path). Change it to `currentFile.Length > 0`

Comment: @Rob THANK YOU! That solved it! I have been working on this for hours trying to figure it out. THANK YOU. Im new and dont know if I can send up vote your comment so thanks so much lol!

Comment: No worries mate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try
{
  if (File.Exists(currentFile))
  {
    if (new FileInfo(currentFile).Length > 0)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
  else
  {
    //show save file dialog
  }

}
catch
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Rob's suggestion this is what I used.

```
try
            {
                // If current file is > 0
                if (currentFile.Length > 0)
                {
                   // Create output file using current file
                   outputFile = File.CreateText(currentFile);
```